# R: How to use lmer for more than two levels?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I want to fit a model with 5 levels. All levels are hierarchical. That is, level 5 is nested in level 4, level4 is nested in level 3, etc. level 2 is nested in level 1. All levels are factors.

Single level and two level models are working well:

```
model1 <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1 | level1), data=data)
model2 <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1 | level1/level2), data=data)
```

I wish to fit a model including all levels. What is the appropriate syntax for lmer?

My ideas so far:

```
model3 <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1 | level1 / level2 / level3 / level4 / level5), data=data)
model4 <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1 | level1 / level2) + (1 | level2 / level3) + (1 | level3 / level4)+ (1 | level4 / level5)
```

*model3* produced this error:

```
Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor level5:(level4:(level3:(level2:level1))) within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible
```

which I can not interpret.

Can you guys hellp me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually create the nested grouping variable through combinations of the five categorical variables. That's what `lmer` does anyway.

Answer (score 2):

See here for an example that might help:

https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer